# Notepad++ : getting the replaced Text in "Find / Replace"

Tags: notepad++, regex

I use regular expressions to find and replace text in some documents.

Im trying to find an Expression like
`img.src.?picture.jpg".*?>`

which finds a string for example like
`IMG alt="" src="picture.jpg" width=461 align=baseline height=72>`

Now I want to use that found string and save it in the replacement text in a comment like:
`img.src.?newpicture.jpg".*?> COMMENT: OLDSTRING`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your find string in brackets
`(img.src.?picture.jpg".*?>)`,

so you can refer to it using `\1`:
`\1 COMMENT: OLDSTRING`

Comment: I'm happy it works, please consider accepting it to mark your question answered.